# How can I create an array of pointer and points it to NULL using **P?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, null-pointer

How can I create an array of pointer using  **P and point it to NULL?

Let's say I have coded as below .

```
struct s
{
    float  a ;
    char x ;
} ;

s  **p ;

p = new ( s  * [10] ) ;
```

Now I want to make some of them as NULL

```
p[0] = NULL ;

p[5] = NULL ;
```

If I simply coded as above then it gives me a warning and also the above method is wrong in how it makes the variable NULL. So how to do I do this?

Comment: What warning do you see ?

Comment: Statement has no effect on line where pointer is made to null.

Comment: None of the answers are correct according to my requirement ....

Answer (score 0):

If you need that elements of the array were zero initialized you can write

```
p = new s * [10] {};
```

Comment: I don't need all element to make zero or NULL i need only some of them and also it gives compilation error on my pc .

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
p = new s*[10];
p[0] = NULL;
p[5] = NULL;
```

If the error is something like

```
error: ‘NULL’ was not declared in this scope
```

then, either

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

in the beginning, or

```
p[0] = 0;
p[5] = 0;
```

Comment: Both are same either we can code it as p = new s *[10] ; or p=new ( s * [10] ) ;

Comment: What's the warning, then?

Comment: @ timaru There is no  error message . This gives a warning message and doing  this is illegal , illegal in the sense if we coded as above than it can not be made  NULL . There may be cause that pointer to  pointer can not be made as NULL .

Answer (score 0):

I've coded this

```
#include<cstdlib> //NULL definition

struct s{
  float a;
  char c;
};

int main (int argc, char **argv){
  s **p = new s*[10];
  p[0] = NULL;
  p[5] = NULL;
  return 0;
};
```

in test.cpp and complied it with `g++ ./test.cpp` and got no warning or error.

So please provide the whole code you are trying to compile and the compiler output. Otherwise it is hard to help you.

Comment: @sonu I got the code you give me and there is a problem when you try to pass the result of deque to inque because you have decalared the inque to get reference to pointer and you can make a reference only from lvalue, but deque returns rvalue, so change inque argument type from dary *& to dary *. But you code is hard to read and I can't understand how your question is connected to the code you provide in the comment above.

Comment: OK forget about that statement and check statement of crate function  . Where I have created the point cptr using new and I made all of them as NULL using for loop . In for loop it is giving no effect to make it NULL .

Comment: @ just http://textuploader.com/d3uk try this uploaded new version with modified inque argument .

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an array of type S pointer with length 10, all containing null. I would get into the habbit of using nullptr. NULL is 0 of type int where nullptr is 0 of type void* (void pointer)

```
struct S
{
    float  a ;
    char x ;
};

int main()
{
    S** p = new S*[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        p[i] = nullptr;
    }
}
```

nullptr was added in C++ 11 so that the compiler would know the difference between calling these two functions.

```
void setValue(int value);

void setValue(int* pointer);
```

Comment: In old compiler like code:blocks , cfree does not support nullptr .

Comment: I apologize, I thought this was the standard.